# unable to run virtual machine through vagrant up

Tags: github, vagrant, virtualbox

I tried to run a virtual machine through vagrant over VirtualBox. I installed VirtualBox and then Vagrant. Then, I cloned a repository from github using `git clone http://github.com/<username>/fullstack-nanodegree-vm fullstack`. Then, I changed directory to `fullstack` . In the git shell, I then run vagrant init and then tried to add box using `vagrant box add hashicorp/precise64` but I got error as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Then, I tried adding box using `vagrant box add hashicorp/precise64 --insecure` and I got this result.[image]

Then, I ran `vagrant up` and then `vagrant ssh`. But, Still git shell is suggesting to run `vagrant up` again.[image]

Please suggest something.

EDIT: After moving my project to `C:\Nanodegree`, I ran `vagrant up` and `vagrant ssh` but still getting problems.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to ruby bug with directory with spaces.

Move your project out of the `$USER_HOME` directory or choose to have your username without any space (it will save you some issues if you have to work with some Linux tools)

Your Vagrantfile does not contain any information about the box to be used.
make sure to edit your `Vagrantfile` and have the following line in the file

```
config.vm.box = 'hashicorp/precise64'
```

NB: Its better to copy/paste the text of your terminal rather than having screenshot.

Comment: I have edited my question after following the steps you mentioned. Please suggest something else.

Comment: As mentioned above, it looks like you didn't set the config.vm.box = 'hashicorp/precise64' Please change the value from base to hashicorp/precise64 and run again.

Comment: After editing your `Vagrantfile`, you may need to run `vagrant destroy` to first destroy the previous vagrant box that failed to install properly. After doing this, and having edited your `Vagrantfile` (replacing `config.vm.box = 'base'` with `config.vm.box = 'hashicorp/precise64'`), running `vagrant up` should do the trick